# Crashlytics velocity alerts for non-fatal issues

Tags: crashlytics

I use Crashlytics to log a non-fatal issue whenever the backend returns unexpected data. Is there a way to get notified when the frequency of this issue suddenly increases? Basically something like the "Issue Velocity Alert" that works for non-fatals too.

Comment: Has this feature come to Crashlytics in the end? If not did go with another service to achieve this alert?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right now we only show notifications for velocity alerts for fatal crashes. However, I'll let the team know you are interested so we can think about this going forward. -Todd from Fabric :)

Comment: So even Google cloud function can't capture velocity event for non-fatal issue?

Comment: So... any progress on this? 